# Como puedo reemplazar en un string de 0 a 1

Tags: javascript, java

Buenas tengo un incoveniente, deseo su gentil ayuda.
Dentro de mi codigo hay una parte especifica en que debo recorrer un binario cualquiera e ir cambiando si es 0 por 1 mediante un ciclo for

```
public void validar_mascara(int cd,int po) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String oc4
    oc4=m_de4.getText();
    if(cd>=24) {
        aqui debo de escribir el ciclo para intercambiar los 0 por 1
    }
```

Comment: Javascript o Java?

Comment: lo estoy haciendo mediante eclipse

Comment: Si es un código binario, entiendo que en el String solo hay 0 y 1. Tal cual como dices en el enunciado cambias los 0 por 1. ¿ocurre lo mismo al reves? cambiar 1 por 0.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, ve iterando caracter a caracter y si es un 0 pones un 1 y si no pones el caracter.

```
String cadena = "0001111";
String cadenaReemplazada = "";
for(i<0;i<cadena.lenght;i++){
    char caracter = cadena.charAt(i);
    if(caracter == '0'){
       cadenaReemplazada = cadenaReemplazada + "1";
    }else{
       cadenaReemplazada = cadenaReemplazada + String.valueOf(caracter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero para que tengas una idea estoy haciendo un programa de subnetting donde uso la mascara en binaria para obtener los host... en este caso, como ejemplo, si yo quisiera que solo en el ultimo octeto de la mascara en binaria cambiar los dos primeros bits los demas deberian de mantenerse en 0 pero con la ayuda que me diste se me trunca a que todos se hagan 1

Comment: ¿Como sería tu entrada?

Comment: Pareciera raro pero cuando te di la explicacion anterior se me vino a la mente una forma mas facil, ahora ya lo hice te agradezco...